# Не срабатывает transition для outline

Tags: css, transition

Хотелось бы сделать плавный эффект при наведении на ссылку, но почему-то не срабатывает transition.
http://codepen.io/leon4y/pen/kXOEAJ

## HTML

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Начало</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Скидки</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Меню</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

## CSS

```
nav{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
nav ul li{
    margin-left: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #656565;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    outline: #656565 solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `border` правильнее будет:

```css
}
nav{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}
nav ul li{
 margin-left: 15px;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #656565;
 padding: 8px 15px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  
  border: transparent solid 1px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
 border: #656565 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Начало</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Скидки</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

Но можно и с outline:

```css
}
nav{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}
nav ul li{
 margin-left: 15px;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #656565;
 padding: 8px 15px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  
  outline: transparent solid 1px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
 outline: #656565 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Начало</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Скидки</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```